# Do you remember the latest version of jira standalone with unlimited user free?

Tags: jira

I'm a student but I need download and install jira, the current version is 7.1 and for standalone server you have 30 days demo, Somebody tell me that he has installed version 5.2.1 and he has unlimited users and unlimited days. I want know the latest version before the current demo limitation of days and users.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

JIRA demo licences all have a time limit of 30 days and no user limit.

Comment: I think that you don't understand my question

Comment: I think he does. Just keep using the evaluation licenses.

Comment: it is not an option, install a new system each 30 days